# Model binding to formview when Gridview Edit button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, model-binding, formview

I have searched here and on google as well.Things are not working so I'm posting this.

I have two controls GridView and FormView.I am using Model binding in my project.

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" ItemType="Sample.Shared.ViewModel.ProfileMasterView"
             AutoGenerateColumns="false" SelectMethod="Select_GridView">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="EmailAddress" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Edit_Profile" OnClick="btnEdit_OnClick" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# BindItem.Id %>" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

<asp:FormView ID="fvProfile" runat="server" RenderOuterTable="False" ItemType="Sample.Shared.ViewModel.ProfileMasterView"
                DefaultMode="Insert" InsertMethod="Insert_Profile" >
```

I want to open FormView in Edit mode , where in gridview i am sending id of that record.On button click i want to change formview mode by calling BLL method which takes that Id from button click and retrieved record displayed in form view in edit mode.
Please help me , how can i implement this or any other similar way using model binding only,
Thank you.

As no one seems to answer this.I have found work around and also proper method for doing,I will add the answer as i get time from work.

Answer (score -1):

before

asp:Button ID="Edit_Profile" OnClick="btnEdit_OnClick" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# BindItem.Id %>"

asp:FormView ID="fvProfile" runat="server" RenderOuterTable="False" ItemType="Sample.Shared.ViewModel.ProfileMasterView"
                DefaultMode="Insert" InsertMethod="Insert_Profile"

after

asp:Button ID="Edit_Profile" OnCommand="btnEdit_OnClick" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# BindItem.Id %>"

asp:FormView ID="fvProfile" runat="server" RenderOuterTable="False" ItemType="Sample.Shared.ViewModel.ProfileMasterView" SelectMethod="Get"
                DefaultMode="Insert" InsertMethod="Insert_Profile"

```
    protected void btnEdit_OnClick(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        gId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        fvProfile.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
        fvProfile.Visible = true;
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        fvProfile.DataBind();
    }

    public DAL2.Models.OfficialDocument Get()
    {
        if(gId == 0)
        {
            ChangeViewMode();
            return null;
        }
        BLL.ManageOfficialDocument mod = new BLL.ManageOfficialDocument();
        var od = mod.GetById(gFILES_ID);
        return od;
    }

private int gId;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.  As it stands, it is unclear.